# How to bind a Dependency Property in a Viewmodel of a Custom Control

Tags: c#, mvvm, viewmodel, dependency-properties

I hope my Title is not too confusing. 
I'm new in MVVM so sorry for some missunderstandings on my side in advance.

I have a Window A in which I put a Custom Control B. B has a ViewModel VM.
in VM i created a Custom Dependenty Property DP.
So no i want to bind DP on a Property in my Window A.

- My question is now how do i do that?
- Is it even possible?
- Or do i have to put my Dependency Property and all other logic in the code behind in this case?

I hope someone can help me and i provided enough information to understand my problem...

Comment: You're having issues because you created a ViewModel for your UserConrol.  Think about it--does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel?  **No.**  Your UserControl should be designed like any other control.  Expose properties on its surface that people bind to.  You can bind to those properties within the UserControl as needed.  And use your codebehind for whatever UI logic you need.  Business logic shouldn't be scoped within a UserControl, so pull any of that out.

Comment: Oh wow yeah makes sense... As i said i don't really know my way around with MVVM. Thank you very much for your quick answer!

Comment: If that's all you need, I've converted it into an answer.  Ask for details and I'll add them.

Comment: Don't update the topic when your question is answered, this isn't a forum or buletin board. Use the "Tick" Icon next to the answer to mark the answer as correct/answered

Comment: @Will Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having issues because you created a ViewModel for your UserConrol. Think about it--does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel? No.

Your UserControl should be designed like any other control. Expose properties on its surface that people bind to. You can bind to those properties within the UserControl as needed. And use your codebehind for whatever UI logic you need.

Business logic shouldn't be scoped within a UserControl, so pull any of that out.